# How to import a lot files at once?

Tags: objective-c

Say I have a ton of small classes that I want to import all at once, is there a way to define a file that is literally just a list of imports and then only import that one file instead of having a long list of imports for each class?

Comment: You should try what you suggested. I think you'll find that it works.

Comment: yes, it work exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggestion will work fine: you can create a header file, and put `#import "..."` directives in it. Then you can include that header in all your files as needed.

Xcode provides an even better solution - the file called `Prefix.pch`. Instead of creating your own header, put the `#import` directives there. The result would be that all your files will implicitly include the files that you import in `Prefix.pch` - you wouldn't even have to import them.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I will certainly implement this!